# Cliking on page link of a wordpress site downloads its html code

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I have created a wordpress site but i could see that if any of its page link is clicked, instead of redirecting to that page its html source code gets downloaded.
here is the link of the site:
http://royalascot.in/

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are setting the page content-type to 'application/x-gzip'.

Try changing it to something like 'text/html'.